# Spring form multiselect Post

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a multiselect field in spring form.

```
<form id="form1" modelattribute="masterInfo">
<select id="company" multiple="multiple" size=2 path="companynamesList[0].companyid" id="companyId">
<option value="1">amazon</option>
<option value="2">ebay</option>
<option value="3">woot</option>
</select>
....

</form>
```

the modelattribute (backing obj) `MasterInfo.java` has a list `companynamesList` and getter and setter for it.

if the user selects both amazon and ebay only ebay(2) is sent the controleller.
I want the list to be populated with both 2 and 1.

Comment: Can you change your path to "companynamesList" ?
which seems to be list.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AutoPopulatingList for conversion, this feature is available in spring for list data conversion to model list. [example](http://java-sandbox.cloudfoundry.com/autopopulatinglist)